# AWS VPC connection between instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm searching for a VPC solution(I'm newbie at this point).

I'm full-stack developer.

First of all let me tell you the past problems I had:

I was using digitalocean.com service(Is very usefull) to create my apps(mysql, nodeapp for backend, nodeapp for frontend, redis, elastic and more).

The big problem I had was setting up machine-to-machine access to work securely, and that was a bummer.

A friend advised me to use aws's VPC so this problem ended.

The question is:

With VPC this problem is over? It is true?

I dont want to set new ssh perms between machine when new app is created :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS VPC can help you to build a virtual network between some EC2.

But you can easily configure some permissions thanks to EC2 Security Groups: if two EC2 instances are in the same VPC (same as default), you can authorize the first EC2 Security Group to the second EC2 Security Group.

In this way, the first instance (and only this instance) will be able to connect to the second.

You can take a look to the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: I just need one VPC, I want to have mysql/redis/elastic in offline mode and only the Rest api 4www. Is possible?

Comment: Yep, just don't create public addresses for your database or redis, your EC2 instance will be able to connect to it with the AWS internal endpoint.

Comment: Oh nice :-D Can "you" explain me more a little bit? I will concede the points 4u.

Comment: Here is a full example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.MySQL.html